# How to import VueLoaderPlugin toTypeScript file?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack

I use TypeScript to generate the webpack config.

According vue-loader [documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/), I installed `vue-loader` and `vue-template-compiler`.

I make sure that `vue-loader` has types definition file:

[image]

However, my TypeScript project does not see plugin.js file.

```
TS2307: Cannot find module 'vue-loader/lib/plugin'.
```

[image]

I tried `"allowJs": true`: no effect.

Also, if to suppress the error message by `@ts-ignore`, my application will be successfully build by webpack. So the problem some missing declaration. Which are?

My `tsconfig.json` settings are:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es6",
    "strict": true,

    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,

    "lib": [
      "es2018"
    ],

    "baseUrl": "./",

    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false
  }
}
```

---

### Update: suggested solution try

[image]

```
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-loader/lib/plugin'
```

The contents of `node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.d.ts` is:

```js
import { Plugin } from 'webpack'

declare namespace VueLoader {
  class VueLoaderPlugin extends Plugin {}
}

export = VueLoader
```

Comment: try like this

import VueLoaderPlugin from 'vue-loader';

Comment: @TonyTom, Thank you for the respond. Unfortunately, zero effect. Error message just becomes to `TS2307: Cannot find module 'vue-loader'.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try this way: `import { VueLoaderPlugin } from "vue-loader";`

this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the plugin into typescript like this:

`import * as VueLoaderPlugin from 'vue-loader/lib/plugin';`

After that you should get a bunch of errors mostly related to [consolidate](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/issues/295), a template engine consolidation library for node.js.

I tried fixing those errors using an approach similar to [Consolidate - Webpack build fails #295](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/issues/295#issuecomment-368311241) but could not get a working webpack configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, I got another error. This time, TypeScript could no find `node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.d.ts` file ... If you have the time, please check the update in the answer field.